# How to show specific subcategory for a selected category in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

Recently I'm working on a blog. where a post has category and subcategory.
This is my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.title}"

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    details = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, default=1,blank=True, 
        null=True, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        null=True)

    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    featured_image = models.ImageField( 
        upload_to="post_featured_image",null=False )

    content = RichTextUploadingField()
    podcast = models.FileField(upload_to="post_podcast", 
        blank=True,null=True)

    uploaded_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    viewed = models.IntegerField(default=0,editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"
```

Now I can choose category and subcategory for a post from Django admin panel. But the problem is I can choose one category and any subcategory even the subcategory is not the child of the selected category. So a post has a category and a subcategory. But the subcategory's parent category is not same as post's category. So I want that I can only choose those subcategories which is the child of selected categories that I choose for the post. Like next field has to be dependent on the previous field. How to do that? 
sorry for my bad English. Thank you.

Comment: You're going to have to use Javascript if you want to do this on one page.
Though I suppose you could combine category and subcategory into one `<select>` input. But that would be clumsy.

Perhaps the admin is not the best place to do this, it would be easier on a form that you build yourself.

Comment: Thank you. But is there any way to edit admin panel or add own javascript in admin panel page?

Comment: There is, you can just replace the admin template by putting it in `templates/admin/my_app/` and give it the same name as the template you're replacing. Se the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-overriding-templates